# How to call a web api method in Action Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api2 method which is returning HttpResponseMessage

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Tokenize(Tokenize tokenize)
    {
        string requesterIPAddress = "";
        try
        {
            // Get Requester IP Address
            RequestIPService requestIPService = new RequestIPService();
            requesterIPAddress = requestIPService.GetRequesterIP();

            //generate token and insert into Token.TokenStore table and return result
            TokenizerService tokenizerService = new TokenizerService();
            string token = tokenizerService.Tokenizer(tokenize.APIKey, tokenize.MerchantID, tokenize.StoreValue, tokenize.StoreType);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

now i have a client requirement that i have to call this API method in Action result

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Tokenize tokenize)
    {
        TokenizeController tokenizeApi = new TokenizeController();
        HttpResponseMessage response = tokenizeApi.Tokenize(tokenize);
        return View(response);
    }
```

But in last line of APi method's try block i.e.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
```

it gives me an error value can not be null

though API method working well with Ajax Call

**Can anyone tell how to return HttpResponseMessage**

Comment: Could you just use `HttpClient` to actually create a web request and call your webapi action? Personally I'd just refactor it so the code that `Tokenize` and `Index` both use is somewhere else and call that in both methods.

Comment: I do exactly what @GeorgeDuckett said. Put your code somewhere else, then call that method from the webapi and your action result.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - It is working well with http client
Thanks George

Answer (score 0):

Use `new HttpResponseMessage()` instead of `Request.CreateResponse`.  The only functionality you will lose is conneg.  If you use `new StringContent(token)` as the content, then the response will come back as `text/plain`.